# Equation showing error "Missing { inserted" or "Missing } inserted" despite having properly closed every curly braces

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, vscode

```
\begin{align*}
    I(T) = I_m exp(\frac{E}{k T_m}) exp(- \frac{E}{k(T_m)^2}) \int_{T_m}^{T} exp(\frac{E}{k T_m} - \frac{E dT^'}{k T^'})    
\end{align*}
```

This line of code is giving me trouble as I get the missing { error no matter how much I try to correct it.
This line of code works fine in Overleaf from which my friend sent me but not working with my installed LaTeX library along with VS Code. Any fixes?

Comment: Unrelated: don't use `^'` just use `' `  it us redefined in math mode as `^{\prime} ` which is what you want.

Comment: Are you sure the error is in this piece of code? If so please provide a full minimal example others can copy and use to get the same error you get.

Comment: @daleif Know what? that exactly was the issue. Now it's fine. And yes that line was troublemaker not rest of the document. Thanks

Comment: @daleif actually that is related here (`\halign` weirdness:-)

Comment: @Vaishnav but you should always provide a full document (as in my answer) so people can test the code and possible answers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not at pc so couldn't test it. Saw your a swer as I posted the comment

Comment: @daleif I'll remember that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the incorrect input `T^'` which should be `T'` but also `\exp` and do not use `align` for single line displays, so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    I(T) = I_m \exp(\frac{E}{k T_m}) \exp(- \frac{E}{k(T_m)^2}) \int_{T_m}^{T} \exp(\frac{E}{k T_m} - \frac{E dT'}{k T'})  
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, the parentheses are really ugly, that size.

Comment: Solved! Thank you :)